# Shared memory handling for mixed C/FORTRAN program in cygwin

Tags: c, linux, cygwin, fortran, shared-memory

I am porting to cygwin a program in FORTRAN/C that relies on C routines to create a shared memory region allowing various independent FORTRAN routines to share data. Program compiles and runs ok on Linux with g77/gcc compilers. I am compiling on cygwin 1.7.33-2(0.280/5/3)with gfortran/gcc (4.8.3).

One C routine creates the shared memory section of a user-defined size. This seems to work just fine, although I had to add two lines to the sys/shm.h file:

```
#define SHM_R        0400        /* or S_IRUGO from <linux/stat.h> */
#define SHM_W        0200        /* or S_IWUGO from <linux/stat.h> */
```

The shm library functions seem to return reasonable info (page size).

Each FORTRAN routine then calls a C routine to find the shared memory, with a C routine returning pointers to two positions in the section intended for different kinds of data:

```
#define PAGESIZE    1024

int findshm(
    char    **pptr, /* Address of the parameter pointer */
    float   **cptr) /* Address of the data pointer */

    .... calls to shm library functions ....
shmaddr = 0;
p = shmat(shmid, shmaddr, (SHM_R | SHM_W)); 

/* Store the pointers */
*pptr = p;
*cptr = (float *) (p + PAGESIZE);

return npages;
```

The calling FORTRAN code looks like this:

```
integer pptr, cptr       
integer npages                     
npages = findshm(pptr, cptr)
```

Although the total size of the created memory section `npages` is ok, the amount of memory following cptr is too small on cygwin (but not in Linux) and the program crashes for larger datasets with

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
```

Thinking it might have to do with the different underlying data types for the pointers (integer vs char/float) in the C versus FORTRAN code, I tried changing the type definitions of the pointers within the FORTRAN routines to

```
byte pptr       
real*4 cptr
```

and it all compiles and runs, but gives exactly the same runtime error, and doesn't explain why the program works in Linux.

Not sure what I can do at this point (what to look out for, where to get help), so input appreciated.

*Edit*

It turns out that in the section in the code labelled

```
    .... calls to shm library functions ....
```

there is a line

```
shmid = shmget(key, PAGESIZE, IPC_ALLOC);
```

with parameters defined earlier as `PAGESIZE=512` and `IPC_ALLOC=0`, that caused the problem. The call in Linux seems to return the shmid associated with the key without performing a memory allocation, whereas in cygwin it results in a memory allocation to a limit of 4k that leads to the seg fault.

Comment: Not a Fortran coder, but did you look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gfortran/Working-with-Pointers.html?

Comment: Just as an irrelevant side note (which might fall under "don't fix it if it isn't broken"), POSIX shared memory (`shm_open(3)` with `mmap(2)`) is usually a bit nicer to work with on modern *nix systems that provide it. (Not sure if cygwin does.) `shmat(2)` is part of the older System V shared memory interface.

Comment: @Ulfalizer Hadn't seen the link, thanks for pointing out, looking at it now.

Comment: @Ulfalizer This is "legacy" code but straightforward enough to work on modern Linux. Not sure I could handle the translation to a different memory handling method but I'll look into it - thanks.

Comment: Yeah, no need to rewrite it if it's working fine. Just in case you weren't aware of it. System V shared memory isn't even that bad compared to System V semaphores, which are horribly overcomplicated compared to POSIX semaphores. :)

Comment: @Ulfalizer Just letting you know this question was solved, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by cygwin programmers. It involved a patch of the cygwin1 DLL although workarounds are possible by passing additional information about the size of the shm section.